# fixedLengthList - freezed & dart

Tags: dart, freezed

How to make fixedLengthList in class model using @freezed?

```
@freezed
class Example with _$Example {
  factory Example({
    List<int> example, // this list should be max 5 positions, not more
  }) = _Example;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
@freezed
class Example with _$Example {
  @Assert('example.length <= 5', 'this list should be max 5 positions, not more')
  factory Example({
    List<int> example
  }) = _Example;
}
```